# Corona SDK Lua: Moving items from one table to another

Tags: lua, coronasdk, lua-table

I'm new to corona and was trying to do some kind of object pooling on moving platforms.  When they exit the screen theyre moved from `visibleBlocks` to `blocks`.  When I log counts of both my tables the numbers dont match the way they should.. and there are long gaps in my blocks appearing on screen.

My blocks generation:

```
local color = 'red'
for i = 1, 10 do 
    local block = display.newRect( 0, 0, 60, 2 )
    block.index = i
    block.name = 'block'
    block.isVisible = false
    physics.addBody( block, 'static' )
    blocks[i] = block
    sceneGroup:insert( block )

    block.color = color

    color = switchColor(block)  
end
```

code detecting when blocks left the screen

```
function update()

    for k, block in pairs(visibleBlocks) do
        block.y = block.y - 1
        if block.y < 0 then
            removeBlock(block)
        end
    end
```

removeblock code

```
function removeBlock(block)

    block.isVisible = false
    block.isBodyActive = false
    blocks[block.index] = block
    visibleBlocks[block.index] = nil


    print (' ')
    print( 'blocks: ' .. #blocks)
    print( 'visible blocks: ' .. #visibleBlocks )

end
```

addblock which is executed on a timer

```
function addBlock()
    local block = table.remove( blocks )
    if block ~= nil then
        block.isVisible = true
        block.isBodyActive = true
        visibleBlocks[block.index] = block

        block.x = math.random( 
            block.contentWidth/2 + 20, 
            display.contentWidth - block.contentWidth/2 - 20 
        )
        block.y = display.contentHeight

    end
end
```

my console output looks like this:

```
Oct 23 08:50:16.281: blocks: 0
Oct 23 08:50:16.281: visible blocks: 9
Oct 23 08:50:17.289:  
Oct 23 08:50:17.290: blocks: 0
Oct 23 08:50:17.290: visible blocks: 8
Oct 23 08:50:18.329:  
Oct 23 08:50:18.329: blocks: 10
Oct 23 08:50:18.329: visible blocks: 7
Oct 23 08:50:19.353:  
Oct 23 08:50:19.354: blocks: 9
Oct 23 08:50:19.354: visible blocks: 6
Oct 23 08:50:20.313:  
Oct 23 08:50:20.314: blocks: 8
Oct 23 08:50:20.314: visible blocks: 5
Oct 23 08:50:21.339:  
Oct 23 08:50:21.340: blocks: 0
Oct 23 08:50:21.340: visible blocks: 10
Oct 23 08:50:22.376:  
Oct 23 08:50:22.376: blocks: 7
Oct 23 08:50:22.376: visible blocks: 10
Oct 23 08:50:23.390:  
Oct 23 08:50:23.390: blocks: 6
Oct 23 08:50:23.390: visible blocks: 10
Oct 23 08:50:24.392:  
Oct 23 08:50:24.393: blocks: 5
Oct 23 08:50:24.393: visible blocks: 10
Oct 23 08:50:25.457:  
Oct 23 08:50:25.457: blocks: 4
Oct 23 08:50:25.458: visible blocks: 10
```

these numbers should always add up to 10 right?  something isnt quite right here

Comment: I don't fully follow the logic here but you are almost certainly creating "holes" in your tables by recycling indices between them like that. And `#` is only defined on tables without holes.

Answer (score 0):

By saying `visibleBlocks[block.index] = nil` in `removeBlock`, you are creating holes in your "array", which means what `#` does is no longer clearly defined.  As an example,

```
function footest( t )  print( ("%d,%s"):format( #t, tostring( t[2] ) ) )  end
footest { 1, nil, 3 }
--> 3,nil
footest { 1, [3] = 3 }
--> 1,nil
t = { 1, 2, 3 } ; t[2] = nil ; footest( t )
--> 3,nil
u = { 1, 2, 3 } ; u[1] = nil ; footest( u )
--> 3,2
u[2] = nil ; footest( u )
--> 3,nil
u[3] = nil ; footest( u )
--> 0,nil
```

(at least this is what *currently* happens on my machine…  While you could look at the source and find out what will happen in all of these cases for the particular version you're using, the reference manual just says that what happens is undefined.)

---

So how to fix this?

One way of going about this would be to use `table.remove` instead of `nil`-ing fields.  (`table.remove( t, n )` will shift all elements "right of" `n` in the "array" one to the left to close the gap, that is for

```
t = { [1] = 1, [2] = 2, [3] = 3 }
```

saying

```
table.remove( t, 1 )
```

results in

```
t = { [1] = 2, [2] = 3, [3] = nil }
```

and not leaving a gap inside the array.)  This works well when you depend on the order of things in the table/"array" but not on their absolute position.

Unfortunately, it seems you're relying on fixed positions for all blocks (`block.index`) – if so, this won't work.  (If this *does* work and I'm just mis-interpreting your code, it's probably the simplest way to fix this.)

---

So a better way might be to assign `false` instead of `nil`.  You'll have to adjust `update` (and maybe other code that I didn't see), but the changes are minor:

Your

```
function update()
    for k, block in pairs(visibleBlocks) do
        block.y = block.y - 1
        if block.y < 0 then
            removeBlock(block)
        end
    end
end
```

turns into

```
function update()
    for k, block in ipairs(visibleBlocks) do
        if block then
            block.y = block.y - 1
            if block.y < 0 then
                removeBlock(block)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The first change – replacing `pairs` with `ipairs` – is something that you **should** do anyway whenever you're using a table as an array.  (`ipairs` will stop at the first gap, which means if you accidentally create a hole, a lot of stuff will be missing and you get a pretty obvious error that's easier to debug than those minor glitches.  Also, if your array contains holes, `pairs` may not iterate over everything in ascending order – try it with `t = { 1, 2, 3, [9] = 9, [12] = 12 }`, iterating with `pairs` may produce the order 1, 2, 3, 12, 9!)

The only other change is checking `if block then …`, because some blocks may be absent, as represented by `false`, and will not silently be skipped like when using `nil` and `pairs`.

The result will be good if you depend on position (and, implicitly, order) of elements in the table/"array", and the "is this actually a block?"-check isn't too bad.

---

A third option – if you're relying neither on the order nor on the absolute position of elements – would be not trying to use the table as an array.  Just use each block as a key and assign a dummy value (commonly `true`) to its entry.  (As a bonus, you don't need to remember an extra `block.index` – the block *is* the index!)

To add a block, just say `blocks[block] = true`, to remove, just say `blocks[block] = nil`.  To iterate over all blocks,

```
for block in pairs( blocks ) do
    …
end
```

but if you need to count the blocks, you'll need a function like

```
function size( t )
    local count = 0
    for _ in pairs( t ) do  count = count + 1  end
    return count
end
```

This version will break horribly when you rely on the relative order as the drawing order or something like that:  Whenever you insert an element, the order of all entries may change completely, which would result in blocks randomly popping above/below others. Compare:

```
t = { [5] = 1, [2] = 1, [8] = 1 }
for k in pairs( t ) do print( k ) end
--> 8, 5, 2
t[3] = 1
for k in pairs( t ) do print( k ) end
--> 8, 5, 2, 3
t[6] = 1
for k in pairs( t ) do print( k ) end
--> 2, 3, 5, 6, 8
```

(and you could get a completely different order if you run this.)

If this potential problem doesn't apply this may actually result in the simplest code overall (even though you'll probably have to restructure a bit more.)